# Getting specific line of text through elements

Tags: excel, xml, vba, element, worksheet

How do I get the whelping date in the breeding section of the webpage? It comes up as 'object doesn't support this property or method.

update: thankyou once again Zwenn for fixing my mistakes.

```
      Sub GetADog2()
        
        URL2 = "https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/Dog/Details/-370317"
        Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
        Dim node1 As HTMLHtmlElement
        Dim Element1 As Object
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        With http
            .Open "GET", URL2, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        'Problem starts here
        Set Element1 = html.getElementById("breedingArea").getElementsByClassName("display-value")(0)
        ws.Cells(5, 1) = Trim(Replace(Element1.innerText, "/", "~"))
        
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use always `Option Explicit` as first line in every module and sort your code. `getElementsByClassName()` can't be use in that way if you use early and late binding. It don't work with late binding. I don't know why it works in two lines with a mixture.

```
Sub GetADog2()
  
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
  Dim html As New HTMLDocument
  Dim Element1 As HTMLHtmlElement
  Dim node1 As HTMLHtmlElement
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim url2 As String
  
  url2 = "https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/Dog/Details/-370317"
  Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  
  With http
    .Open "GET", url2, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  'Problem starts here
  Set Element1 = html.getElementById("breedingArea")
  Set node1 = Element1.getElementsByClassName("display-value")(0)
  ws.Cells(5, 1) = Trim(Replace(node1.innerText, "/", "~"))
End Sub
```